# Android Studio 3.6: ClassNotFound androidxwork.R$bool

Tags: android-studio

after updating to Android Studio 3.6. I get the following error when starting the app:

```
>  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Landroidx/work/R$bool;
>         at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.<init>(WorkManagerImpl.java:210)
>         at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:186)
>         at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:204)
>         at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer.onCreate(WorkManagerInitializer.java:40)
>         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
>         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
>      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.R$bool" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/de.faunamapper.mapper-bEGLlrk4-nWlyt-UAmFK4w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.faunamapper.mapper-bEGLlrk4-nWlyt-UAmFK4w==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/de.faunamapper.mapper-bEGLlrk4-nWlyt-UAmFK4w==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64,
> /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
```

Before everything worked fine. How to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537638/how-to-resolve-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-view-viewon

Comment: tried the solutions of that post, but didn't work,,,

Comment: Ok, solved this issue by making a new Project and copying the source code to the new project folder. Very annoying, that after each Studio update sth breaks.

Comment: I got the same issue, but only after upgrading gradle from 3.5.3 to 3.6.0 and gradle distribution from gradle-5.4.1-all.zip to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip. Downgrading back fixed this issue.

Comment: Yes, I also played around with the gradle version and came to the same conclusion. Downgrade only fixed the issue in my case, if the app was freshly installed.

Comment: I deleted the build gradle cache and the `files-2.1/androidx.work` folder, did a clean, did a build, and then it worked. Wtf.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Even that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I Resolved It by Updating ObjectBox to 2.5.1 version.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.R$bool" on path: DexPathList`

Ref : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157673281
Hope this can help