# Unexpected messages on Android after upgrading to NativeScript v5.1

Tags: android, nativescript

I have upgraded an existing app from {N} 4.5 to 5.1.  When I run the app on an Android emulator, I receive a set of messages that I did not receive before.  It's not clear (at least, to me) if these are error messages or not.

Searches on the message text haven't yielded any helpful information.

```
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean,
 java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, l
ong, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.la
ng.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.C
lass, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.065 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(int, int, java.lang.String, int, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:-2)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(int, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1120)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:1000)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, long, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:987)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:967)
01-21 11:48:14.066 14949 14949 I zygote  :   at java.lang.Object com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object[]) (Runtime.java:959)
```

These messages appear while the app initializes.  The app seems to run OK, 'tho I am having an issue with a geolocation call.  I wanted to understand if these messages are an issue or not.

Comment: You copied the stack trace, but omitted the exception name (and message). They appear above this stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more info here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4300 and here
[AndroidX:Appcompat I:art error android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782548/androidxappcompat-iart-error-android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener/52954286#52954286)