# Didn't find class "android.view.View?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm trying to access a different xml file by using an inflater.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelist_item, null);

TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description);
title.setText("My Awesome Text");
```

But I get the errors
"Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList" and "Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class"

I'm not sure what's causing the problem?

Here's my log:

```
03/08 20:36:43: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 26.
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 4892 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void edu.cuhk.csci3310.cusweetnames.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:36)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
I/zygote:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.cuhk.csci3310.cusweetnames-mm4Y3gQqoVOgcskW219QlQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/edu.cuhk.csci3310.cusweetnames-mm4Y3gQqoVOgcskW219QlQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void edu.cuhk.csci3310.cusweetnames.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:36)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
```

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

imagelist_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/rl">

        <ImageView
            android:id ="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/p0_frozen_yogurt_milano_fresh_cafe"
            style="@style/image_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"

            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="197dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-177dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/dessert_name"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"

            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="197dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-177dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/location"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="197dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-177dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/rating"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star"
            android:drawablePadding="7dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.cuhk.csci3310.cusweetnames"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: show your xml file please

Comment: @Kirguduck I've added the xml content in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957944/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener)

Comment: @Kirguduck I've already seen the other solutions but my gradle implementation is in the 'implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' format.

Comment: show your gradle file plase

Comment: did you try to downgrade to version 27 as below   compileSdkVersion 27

targetSdkVersion 27

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: @Kirguduck I get the error message " The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.3.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used."

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat` does not implement `View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener` in the new androidx package structure and only implements it starting on API 28 in the support lib structure (at least in version 28.0.0). Therefore the warning appears on devices with API <28 and does not appear on those >=28.
try to add this annotation to your `onCreate()`

```
@RequiresApi(28)
public void onCreate...
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782548/androidxappcompat-iart-error-android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener)
but it will not work with devices before Api28

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work. I still get the same error messages.

Comment: @JangHyeonChoi i suspect you try to launch your app on Nexus 5X API 26. Read my answer above